# What is lockd and why is it not running?

Tags: 16.04, nfs

On a number of boxes that I help managing I have strangest issue. It usually manifest itself a day or more since last reboot.

When I try to mount an nfs share

```
sudo mount -t nfs  192.168.8.205:/export /mnt/andrew
```

I get:

```
mount.nfs: rpc.statd is not running but is required for remote locking.
mount.nfs: Either use '-o nolock' to keep locks local, or start statd.
mount.nfs: an incorrect mount option was specified
```

When it enters this state nothing else seems to help. I tried

```
sudo systemctl restart rpc-statd
sudo systemctl restart rpcbind
```

both server seems to be running, and I cannot see obvious errors:

```
 sudo journalctl -u rpcbind
-- Logs begin at Tue 2019-02-19 18:29:21 UTC, end at Tue 2019-03-26 04:52:48 UTC. --
Feb 25 23:21:11 box1 systemd[1]: Starting RPC bind portmap service...
Feb 25 23:21:11 box1 rpcbind[29172]: rpcbind: xdr_/run/rpcbind/rpcbind.xdr: failed
Feb 25 23:21:11 box1 rpcbind[29172]: rpcbind: xdr_/run/rpcbind/portmap.xdr: failed
Feb 25 23:21:11 box1 systemd[1]: Started RPC bind portmap service.
Mar 24 18:59:57 box1 systemd[1]: Stopping RPC bind portmap service...
Mar 24 18:59:57 box1 systemd[1]: Stopped RPC bind portmap service.
Mar 24 18:59:57 box1 systemd[1]: Starting RPC bind portmap service...
Mar 24 18:59:57 box1 systemd[1]: Started RPC bind portmap service.

asavinykh@box1:~$  sudo journalctl -u rpc-statd
-- Logs begin at Tue 2019-02-19 18:29:21 UTC, end at Tue 2019-03-26 04:56:13 UTC. --
Feb 25 23:21:11 box1 systemd[1]: Stopped NFS status monitor for NFSv2/3 locking..
Feb 25 23:21:11 box1 systemd[1]: Starting NFS status monitor for NFSv2/3 locking....
Feb 25 23:21:11 box1 systemd[1]: Started NFS status monitor for NFSv2/3 locking..
Mar 24 18:48:49 box1 systemd[1]: Started NFS status monitor for NFSv2/3 locking..
Mar 24 18:48:50 box1 systemd[1]: Started NFS status monitor for NFSv2/3 locking..
Mar 24 18:48:51 box1 systemd[1]: Started NFS status monitor for NFSv2/3 locking..
Mar 24 18:48:53 box1 systemd[1]: Started NFS status monitor for NFSv2/3 locking..
Mar 24 18:48:57 box1 systemd[1]: Started NFS status monitor for NFSv2/3 locking..
Mar 24 18:49:05 box1 systemd[1]: Started NFS status monitor for NFSv2/3 locking..
Mar 24 18:49:22 box1 systemd[1]: Started NFS status monitor for NFSv2/3 locking..
Mar 24 18:49:54 box1 systemd[1]: Started NFS status monitor for NFSv2/3 locking..
Mar 24 18:50:58 box1 systemd[1]: Started NFS status monitor for NFSv2/3 locking..
Mar 24 18:53:00 box1 systemd[1]: Started NFS status monitor for NFSv2/3 locking..
Mar 24 18:55:02 box1 systemd[1]: Started NFS status monitor for NFSv2/3 locking..
Mar 24 18:57:04 box1 systemd[1]: Started NFS status monitor for NFSv2/3 locking..
Mar 24 18:59:07 box1 systemd[1]: Started NFS status monitor for NFSv2/3 locking..
Mar 24 19:01:09 box1 systemd[1]: Started NFS status monitor for NFSv2/3 locking..
Mar 24 19:03:11 box1 systemd[1]: Started NFS status monitor for NFSv2/3 locking..
Mar 24 19:05:13 box1 systemd[1]: Started NFS status monitor for NFSv2/3 locking..
Mar 24 19:06:32 box1 systemd[1]: Started NFS status monitor for NFSv2/3 locking..
Mar 24 19:07:07 box1 systemd[1]: Stopping NFS status monitor for NFSv2/3 locking....
Mar 24 19:07:07 box1 systemd[1]: Stopped NFS status monitor for NFSv2/3 locking..
Mar 24 19:07:07 box1 systemd[1]: Starting NFS status monitor for NFSv2/3 locking....
Mar 24 19:07:07 box1 systemd[1]: Started NFS status monitor for NFSv2/3 locking..
Mar 24 19:07:12 box1 systemd[1]: Started NFS status monitor for NFSv2/3 locking..
```

Note that `rpcbind.xdr` error also appears on the machines where it's still working.

However one thing that IS different on boxes where it is still working and those that it stopped working is this:

```
ps aux | grep lockd
root        26  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   04:08   0:00 [kblockd]
root      3148  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    04:08   0:00 [lockd]
asaviny+ 31517  0.0  0.0  16576  2096 pts/0    S+   04:58   0:00 grep lockd
```

The difference is the `[lockd]` line. It consistently present on the boxes where it still works, and consistently absent on the boxes where it stopped working.

Any idea, what this [lockd] is, how I can re-start it if it stops or how I can make sure that it does not stop.

I tried `systemctl | grep lockd` but that gives nothing.

I also tried `journalctl -xe | grep lockd`, `cat /var/log/kern.log | grep lockd` and `cat /var/log/syslog | grep lockd` all of those return nothing.

Reboot usually clears this condition out.

Answer (score 2):

Read `man nsfd`, it says, in part,

```
   In the /proc filesystem there are 4 files that can be used to  enabled  extra  tracing  of
   nfsd and related code.  They are:
        /proc/sys/sunrpc/nfs_debug
        /proc/sys/sunrpc/nfsd_debug
        /proc/sys/sunrpc/nlm_debug
        /proc/sys/sunrpc/rpc_debug
   They  control tracing for the NFS client, the NFS server, the Network Lock Manager (lockd)
   and the underlying RPC layer respectively.  Decimal numbers can be read from or written to
   these  files.   Each number represents a bit-pattern where bits that are set cause certain
   classes of tracing to be enabled.  Consult the kernel header files to find out what number
   correspond to what tracing.
```

Also see https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/networking_2ndEd/nfs/ch11_02.htm

Answer (score 1):

*Sorry for replying to a question from three years ago, however it's **really** hard to find solid information on this topic online and because I went through the trouble of figuring out the low level details myself, I thought I might as well share my results!*

---

First a general observation: When a process name in the `ps aux` output is wrapped in square brackets like `[lockd]` [this usually signifies](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/22141/44309) that we're dealing with a kernel thread. This explain why there is no `lockd` (or similarly named) executable anywhere in the `$PATH`.

## Confirming that `lockd` is a kernel module

You can use the `lsmod` command to list active kernel modules, for me this indeed shows a `lockd` module (all of the examples I give in this post are based on an Ubuntu 20.04 system):

```
$ lsmod | grep nfs
nfsd                  409600  11
auth_rpcgss            94208  1 nfsd
nfs_acl                16384  1 nfsd
lockd                 102400  1 nfsd
grace                  16384  2 nfsd,lockd
sunrpc                393216  30 nfsd,auth_rpcgss,lockd,nfs_acl
```

The following command find the location of any related files:

```
$ locate lockd.ko
/usr/lib/modules/5.4.0-109-generic/kernel/fs/lockd/lockd.ko
/usr/lib/modules/5.4.0-110-generic/kernel/fs/lockd/lockd.ko
```

Finding these `lockd.ko` files is a definite confirmation that `lockd` is implemented as a kernel thread.

## Who is responsible for starting `lockd`?

Because you mentioned wanting to restart `[lockd]` I got curious who is responsible for starting it, so I investigated a bit:

```
$ dpkg -L nfs-common | xargs -d '\n' grep -s lockd
Binary file /sbin/rpc.statd matches
Binary file /sbin/sm-notify matches
```

Here's what these strings referencing `lockd` actually look like:

```
$ strings /sbin/rpc.statd | grep lock
modprobe lockd

$ strings /sbin/sm-notify | grep lock
/proc/fs/lockd/nlm_end_grace
```

This answers the question I set out to answer when I found this page:

1. The `lockd` daemon is implemented as a kernel thread (and it appears no one is responsible for supervising it and restarting on failure).
2. The `statd` daemon appears to be responsible for loading the `lockd.ko` kernel module (judging by the `strings` output above). Using `apt-get source nfs-common` I was able to confirm that `utils/statd/statd.c` contains a conditional `system("modprobe lockd");` invocation.
3. The `statd` daemon is started and supervised by systemd, the executable is called `rpc.statd` and it's managed by the `rpc-statd.service` unit.

You mention having tried `systemctl restart rpc-statd` and judging by my research that one is responsible for running `modprobe lockd`, so at this point it's hard to say whether a manual `modprobe lockd` command would have helped in your situation, however to anyone encountering this issue I would suggest to try it out.